# jQuery Tools Tabs - Link to tab from another text link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tools

I am using jQuery Tools Tabs ... I am needing to open tabs from a separate link on the same page. Here is my code I am trying.

```
jQuery(function($){

        $('#accord1trig').click(function(){
              $(".accordion").tabs('selected', 1);
        });

        $('#accord2trig').click(function(){
              $(".accordion").tabs('selected', 2);
        });

        $('#accord3trig').click(function(){
              $(".accordion").tabs('selected', 3);
        });

        $('#accord4trig').click(function(){
              $(".accordion").tabs('selected', 4);
        });

});
```

and the html is as follows

```
<a href="#" id="accord1trig">Tab Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="accord2trig">Tab Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="accord3trig">Tab Link 3</a>
<a href="#" id="accord4trig">Tab Link 4</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "separate link" is:

```
<a href="#" id="click-me">Click me</a>
```

and you want it to open "Tab Link 1", you'd change the first jQuery `.click()` in your script to:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('#accord1trig, #click-me').click(function(){
          $(".accordion").tabs('selected', 1);
    });

    // Remainder of your code...

});
```

See how I comma-separated and added `#click-me` to the selector there?

***Update:***

Based on the URL you provided, the following worked for me:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('h4 a[data-tab]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var tab = jQuery('.accordion-toggle:eq(' + (parseInt(jQuery(this).data('tab')) - 1) + ')');
        tab.triggerHandler('click').addClass('current');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I had tried to begin with but had no luck. Here is where I am trying to implement the solution, http://www.peachtreewomensclinic.com/provider/

Trying to link the Physicians, Midwifes, etc to the corresponding tab.

Comment: Thank you very much Coby ... been tearing my hair out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault() to stop the default action.
Also you can condense your code into a single event handler..

Add the HTML-5 data attribute to store the tab info..

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="accord1trig" data-tab="1">Tab Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="accord2trig" data-tab="2">Tab Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="accord3trig" data-tab="3">Tab Link 3</a>
<a href="#" id="accord4trig" data-tab="4">Tab Link 4</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#accord1trig ,#accord2trig ,
                #accord3trig ,#accord4trig  ').on('click' , function(){

       var tab = parseInt( $(this).data('tab') , 10) ;
       $(".accordion").tabs('selected', tab);
 });
```

**OR Simply**

```
 $('[id^="accord"]').on('click' , function(){

           var tab = parseInt( $(this).data('tab') , 10) ;
           $(".accordion").tabs('selected', tab);
     });
```

Comment: I tried this solution but no luck. Here is where I am trying to implement a solution. http://www.peachtreewomensclinic.com/provider/